# Stimulus keyboard events don't appear to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

According to the reference sheet for Stimulus actions, you can define keyboard event descriptors as described [here](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions)

Thus I have a button that goes to the video_container controller:

```
%button{type: "Button", data: {action: "keydown.k->video-container#playPause",
 video: {container: {target: "playButton"}} Play
```

and in my controller:

```
playPause() {
  alert("This event is working")
}
```

I had this working for a click event with:

```
%button{type: "Button", data: {action: "click->video-container#playPause",
 video: {container: {target: "playButton"}} Play
```

But it doesn't work with the keydown or keyup events.  I even added the :prevent option to call preventDefault() but that didn't work either.

Did I miss something?

**EDIT UPDATE**

Further tinkering here.  I found that I could get the enter key event to do something:

```
%button{type: "Button", data: {action: "keydown.enter->video-container#playPause",
 video: {container: {target: "playButton"}} Play
```

But none of the others work.  using space makes the document move downward.

I even tried their example of a compound modifier ctrl+a and that wasn't working either.

Comment: It's much easier to debug Stimulus issues if the question has the actual HTML in it, not everyone that uses Stimulus uses Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will only likely work if you want to access the keypress while a user has focused on the button.

```html
<button type="button" data-action="keydown.k->video-container#playPause">play</button>
```

This will create an event listener on the `button` only, and that event listener will trigger the method `playPause` only if the keydown event is fired and the letter k is pressed.

```html
<button type="button" data-action="keydown.k@document->video-container#playPause">play</button>
```

This will add an event listener to `document`, remember that keypress events bubble. The event listener will trigger for any keyup anywhere in the DOM, irrespective of whether the button is focused. That listener will trigger the `playPause` method on that specific button's attached controller though.

While this may seem a bit counterintuitive, it's actually really powerful and gives you lots of control over behaviour.

A key take home is that `data-action` is basically equivalent to `addEventListener` on the element that has the data attribute. Some events bubble up from their target, some do not. But events can never bubble down to part of the DOM tree, so if you want events that are not inside the element with `data-action` you need to listen at the document or window (aka global event listeners).

https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions#global-events

Comment: thanks!  I got it working by making a document level listener inside stimulus since keydown@document.k wasn't working either.  I just turned that listener off and tried your syntax of keydown.k@document and works.

Comment: Awesome. Glad this answer worked for you.